# Change anchor class in DOM using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

```
<a class="behaviour1" href="link1">Test</a>
```

I have two click events for the class 'behaviour1' and 'behaviour2'.

```
$('.behaviour1').click(function() {
    alert('behaviour - 1');
    $(this).prop('class', 'behaviour2');
});

$('.behaviour2').click(function() {
    alert('behaviour - 2');
    $(this).prop('class', 'behaviour1');
});
```

I would like to change the behaviour of the anchor tag. But it's not working. I'm getting 'behaviour1' everytime. It's not changing to 'behavour2'.

How do i get it to work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The event handlers are attached on page load, changing the classes later doesn't change the event handlers, they are still attached to the same elements regardless of what classes you add later.

You have to delegate or change the way this works completely, the first option being the easiest :

```
$(document).on('click', '.behaviour1', function() {
    alert('behaviour - 1');
    $(this).prop('className', 'behaviour2');
});

$(document).on('click', '.behaviour2', function() {
    alert('behaviour - 2');
    changeBehaviour();
    $(this).prop('className', 'behaviour1');
});
```

replace `document` with the parent element of the anchor

or a simple toggle switch:

```
$('.behaviour').on('click', function() {
     if ( $(this).data('flag') ) {
         // do behaviour 1
     }else{
         // do behaviour 2
     }

     $(this).data('flag', !$(this).data('flag'));
});
```

Comment: ... or just make a check within the handler (attached to `a` elements with some specific anchoring attribute - `data-*` and `name` look fine for the purpose).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I go with ur solution.

Answer (score 3):

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Y9wdY/)

```
$(document).on('click','.behaviour1, .behaviour2', function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('behaviour1 behaviour2');
    if($(this).hasClass('behaviour1')) {
        alert('behaviour - 1');
    } else {
        alert('behaviour - 2');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

to swap class

```
$(document).on('click','.behaviour1', function() {
    alert('behaviour - 1');
    $(this).removeClass('behaviour1').addClass('behaviour2');
});
$(document).on('click','.behaviour2', function() {
    alert('behaviour - 2');
    $(this).removeClass('behaviour2').addClass('behaviour1');
});
```

<kbd>[**fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/8LG73/)</kbd>

Comment: Since he want's to change the behaviour would that be incorrect? I guess you need to remove behaviour1 then: `$(this).addClass('behaviour2').removeClass('behaviour1');` -- Okay, you edited the answer now.